# Filter specific process(es) in Resource Monitor with command line switch

Tags: windows, command-line, resource-monitor

Is there a way to launch Resource Monitor (resmon.exe) and filter on the Image name of the specific process(es) I want filtered from the command line?

I often need to test 60 or 80 instances of the same application running at the same time. I need to be able to monitor CPU, Memory, and Network resource use. All of the processes have the same name e.g. app.exe, but it's really a pain to tick 80 boxes every time.